# Average PHP developer wanting to move to Python+Django : Directly go with Django or learn the MVC Framework stuff in PHP first?

Tags: php, python, django, cakephp, frameworks

As a student in web development, I work with PHP, mainly through CMSs.

I already know the basic knowledge on the famous MVC design pattern, but now would like to work with a framework.

I've just discovered RoR and Django (respectively Ruby & Python Frameworks) and my first experiments with these frameworks, coupled to the amazing syntaxes of their languages, completely blown me away.

I've already made my choice: Django. (Just to explain : Throughout my researches, I learnt that Django's philosophy is : "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.", and that RoR's motto was exactly the opposite. As a noobie, I think it would be better to work on an app that naturally leads me to the best practices. I can also add that Django seems to be far more transparent and easier to understand, compared to the weird "magic" of Ruby).

The problem is that learning the language and the Framework will may be a difficult task.

My objectives are:
   - Mastering Python + Django.
   - Learn the right way to develop MVC applications.
   - Become productive as fast as possible.

And considering that Django and Cake PHP are quite "similar", should I first learn "MVC in the real world" with Cake PHP before trying to begin directly with Python + Django or not? What would you do, according to your experience?

Pros for learning Cake Php first:
Some of my friends already work with Cake and they could help.
Learning something new is always a nice line to add on the CV.

Cons:
Learning something new is always a bit stupid when you are 95% convinced you won't use it anymore in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest path to Python/Django is to learn Python/Django.

If you invest time in learning something different, it will just create some preconceptions that may not hold in a Python/Django environment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's some info that may help along the way:

1. Don't categorize everything that has routes, controllers, views, etc as "MVC". Django, for example, is self-described as MTV.
2. Django is a fantastic framework and does lots of things well. You will find that the Django and Python library and community is much more "batteries included" than PHP's.
3. Pigeonholing yourself into one language or framework is almost always a bad idea. You don't have to leave PHP, Ruby, etc forever in order to learn Django and Python. Accumulate and assimilate and you'll be more valuable.
4. Just go read the Django documentation end to end and follow the tutorial. It'll take a few days of your time, but you'll save yourself weeks of writing code that someone else has already baked into the framework or Python.